# Is there a way to remove all spaces from a string? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have browsed around and it seems a question similar to this has been asked about removing multiple spaces or spaces at the beginning or end, but my question is can you remove all spaces from a string? (tabs included)
I would like to later combine this with user input so the spaces will be a different spots each time.

Heres an example of what I'm asking, what can go where my comment is to make the two strings equal?

```
var test = "Please Remove Spaces!!!";
var test2 = "PleaseRemoveSpaces!!!";
//function that removes spaces
if (test==test2) 
{
    console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: Split the string by space then join without it

Comment: You can use this "hello world".replace(/ /g, '');, and you will get helloworld.

Comment: `.replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Comment: Technically no, you can't remove all spaces because strings are immutable. You can however create a new string from the original with the spaces removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this easily:

```
var test = "Please Remove Spaces!!!";

// Choice 1: using RegExp
var removed1 = test.replace(/\s/g, '');

// Choice 2: using String methods
var removed2 = test.split(' ').join('');

console.log(removed1, removed2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/CTegL/

Answer (score 1):

```
 test.replace(/[ \t]/g, '')
```

Removes all occurrences of space and tab chars from variable `test`'s value and returns the result.

Comment: @dfsq: It works on node.js, but I see that Chrome doesn't use an empty string as the replacement string, but `undefined` - post updated with specifying an empty string as the replacement string - let me know of any environments where that doesn't work.

Comment: You miss the string to replace by, i.e. `""` in this case.

Comment: Blame my slow mobile data connection for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var test2 = test1.split(' ');
test2 = test2.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to test = test.replace(" ","")

Comment: this will replace only the first occurence

Comment: @ItayB: options such as `g` can only be applied to regexes (e.g., `/ /`).

Answer (score 0):

```
test2 = test.replace(/[\t ]+/g, "");
```

This will replace all spaces and tabs by an empty string, thereby removing them.

If you also want new line characters to be removed you can use

```
/\s+/g
```

as the RegEx instead.

Comment: This is the most complete answer. However a bit overkill, because `\s` already includes tabs so no need to specify `\t`. It can be just `/\s+/g`.

Comment: Good point... Let me change that. Note to self: don't answer questions on StackOverflow while being terribly tired.

Comment: @dfsq: the `+` is overkill too - `g` has that covered. Also note that `\s`, also matches chars. such as `\n` and `\r`, which is, strictly speaking, not what the OP asked for.

Comment: The `+` isn't necessary, but increases performance, because it may reduce the number of replace operations.

Comment: @Cu3PO42: Good point - hadn't thought of that - though you'll probably only notice with large strings - I've run a few tests and on my machine the difference started to be noteworthy at around 100,000 chars.